# What is the difference between /dev/mem, /dev/kmem and /proc/kcore?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

What is the difference between `/dev/mem`, `/dev/kmem` and `/proc/kcore`?

Can I disassemble its contents using tools like `objdump` and `gdb`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/dev/kmem` gives access to the kernel's virtual memory space, and `/dev/mem` gives access to physical memory.

`/proc/kcore` is a pseudofile in ELF `core` format, of the kernel's virtual memory space.  You should be able to examine it with standard ELF utilities, like `objdump` and `gdb` - although you will likely better off to make a regular file copy of it and work on that.

Comment: In laymans terms what is the difference between this virtual memory space and physical memory

Comment: @user567879: The virtual memory address space corresponds to the addresses as seen by the program in question (in this case, the kernel).  The physical memory address space corresponds to the actual memory addresses that are placed on the system bus.  The MMU within the CPU translates virtual addresses into physical addresses.

Comment: @caf _Kernel virtual memory_ does not really make sense. Virtual memory is relative to a process, and the kernel is not a process. In fact, every process' virtual memory contain the same kernel part on top (higher addresses), which is only accessible after a switch in kernel context. `/proc/kcore` is the physical memory.

Comment: @ysomane: I would argue that it *does* make sense - as you point out the 'kernel' part of every process's page tables is the same, and is only accessible in kernel mode.  Those are the addresses "seen" by the kernel - the addresses of kernel objects are virtual addresses in that constant kernel part of the address space.  `/proc/kcore` covers the kernel virtual address space region, not physical memory - though depending on kernel configuration this might well include a mapping of all physical memory.

Comment: @caf You're right on this, my point was in reply to your first comment, which sounds like you considered the kernel as some process. The _kernel virtual memory_ may be considered as the kernel part of the current process's virtual space. What would be odd may be to talk about the _kernel_ **'s** _virtual memory_. For the other point, every documentation I saw talk about physical memory for `/proc/kcore`...