# objdump and udis86 produce different output when disassembling /proc/kcore

Tags: linux, disassembly, objdump

I need to disassemble `/proc/kcore` file in Linux and I need to obtain virtual addresses of some special instructions to put `kprobes` later on it. According to [this document](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) `/proc/kcore` is an image of physical memory, but in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882755/difference-between-kcore-mem-kmem-in-proc-directory) someone answered that it is kernel's virtual memory (exactly what I am looking for).

When I use `objdump` tool to disassemble it, it starts with address something like `f7c0b000`, but [udis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) starts with 0x0 (and totally different instruction). When I try to `grep` some specific instruction, let's say `mov    0xf7c1d60c,%edx`, I got:

**objdump**

```
f7c0b022 mov    0xf7c1d60c,%edx
```

**udis86**

```
290ec02a mov    0xf7c1d60c,%edx
```

It looks like the offset between `udis86` and `objdump` is always `0xbffff000`. Why so strange offset? How can I obtain virtual address of specific instruction? Somewhere I've read, that kernel is statically mapped at virtual address 0xc0000000 + 0x100000. If `/proc/kcore` is really physical image, is it correct only to add 0x100000 to addresses returned by `objdump` and I will get virtual address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`objdump` understands `ELF` format files (such as `/proc/kcore`).  It is able to extract the executable sections of the file while ignoring non-executable content (such as `.note` sections).

You can see the structure of an `ELF` exectuable using the `-h` flag, for example:

```
# objdump -h /proc/kcore
/proc/kcore:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 note0         00001944  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000002a8  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  1 .reg/0        000000d8  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000032c  2**2
                  CONTENTS
  2 .reg          000000d8  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000032c  2**2
                  CONTENTS
  3 load1         00800000  ffffffffff600000  0000000000000000  7fffff602000  2**12
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
(...)
```

It looks like the `udcli` tool from `udis86` probably starts disassembling things from the beginning of the file, which suggests that your output will probably start with a bunch of irrelevant output and it's up to you to figure out where execution starts.

**UPDATE**

Here's the verification.  We use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925075/how-do-you-extract-only-the-contents-of-an-elf-section) to extract the first `load` section from /proc/kcore, like this:

```
# dd if=/proc/kcore of=mysection bs=1 skip=$[0x7fffff602000] count=$[0x00800000]
```

And now if we view that with `udcli`:

```
# udcli mysection
0000000000000000 48               dec eax                 
0000000000000001 c7c060000000     mov eax, 0x60           
0000000000000007 0f05             syscall                 
0000000000000009 c3               ret                     
000000000000000a cc               int3                    
000000000000000b cc               int3
```

We see that it looks almost identical to the output of `objdump -d /proc/kcore`:

```
# objdump -d /proc/kcore
/proc/kcore:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section load1:

ffffffffff600000 <load1>:
ffffffffff600000:       48 c7 c0 60 00 00 00    mov    $0x60,%rax
ffffffffff600007:       0f 05                   syscall 
ffffffffff600009:       c3                      retq   
ffffffffff60000a:       cc                      int3   
ffffffffff60000b:       cc                      int3
```

Comment: That's awesome, it works like a charm, thanks. And what about the addresses?  How can I get virtual address which can be used e.g. for kprobes?

Comment: Ok, I tried to create my own module and dump addresses of some its functions. And when I tried to `grep` these addresses on `objdump -d /proc/kcore`, I really found them there. If you think about it, kcore is in ELF format, so of course there should be virtual addresses, am I right?